# How to correctly select every odd child's first child?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to make all the title `div` bold and red, but the css I have is making all of them bold and red. What is wrong with my css?

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XKYeg/7/).

```
<div id=foo>
    <div>
        <div>title 1</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>data 1</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>title 2</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>data 2</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>title 3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>data 3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>title 4</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>data 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
#foo {
    font-size:8pt;
}
#foo:nth-child(odd):first-child {
    font-weight:bold;
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selector `#foo:nth-child(odd):first-child` applies both pseudo-classes to `#foo` itself. Since `#foo` is indeed the first child, and 1 is an odd number, it matches, causing the font styles to apply to the entire element and its contents (since font styles are inherited).

You need to split the pseudo-classes with some child selectors:

```css
#foo > :nth-child(odd) > :first-child {
    font-weight:bold;
    color:red;
}
```

If the title `div` elements are the only children of their parents then you can safely replace `:first-child` with `div`; there is no point in making sure you select only the first of each:

```css
#foo > :nth-child(odd) > div {
    font-weight:bold;
    color:red;
}
```

And for that matter, since font styles are inherited as I mentioned, you can even leave out the `> div` completely:

```css
#foo > :nth-child(odd) {
    font-weight:bold;
    color:red;
}
```

Of course, feel free to ignore the last two snippets if the innermost `div` elements are not the only children...

Answer (score 1):

Selectors run together are "ANDed" together. So `#foo:nth-child(odd):first-child` will match all those elements who have ID 'foo' and are an odd-child of their parent and are the first child of their parent.

Selectors separated by spaces mean "some descendant of", and by `>` mean "immediate child of".

Did you mean, perhaps, this?

```css
#foo > :nth-child(odd) > :first-child {
    font-weight:bold;
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#foo > div:nth-child(2n+1) {
    font-weight:bold;
    color:red;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/XKYeg/10/)**

(or just `#foo > div:nth-child(odd)`)

Note if you need to target the child div specifically, just add a `div` at the end of either rule. Ex: `#foo > div:nth-child(odd) div`